# R: Wrong density from density plots

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, density-plot

I have a vector which I wanted to plot the density for. But after I plot the density, I found the density I got is wrong(greater than 1).

```
    x <- data.frame(p = c(26.5, 26.34, 26.34, 26.34, 26.34, 26.5, 26.5, 26.34, 26.34, 28.74, 26.5, 28.74, 26.34, 28.74))

    plot(density(x = x$p))
```

[image: Density greater than 1]

And if I round the numbers, I got the right density.
        plot(density(x = round(x$p)))
[image: Correct density values]

ggplot2 gives me the wrong density, too.

```
    ggplot(x)+ stat_density(aes(x=p), geom='line',position="identity")
```

[image]

```
    ggplot(x)+ geom_density(aes(x=p))
```

[image]

Does anyone know what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Looks like your x limits are pretty different. Add to your ggplots `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(24, 32)` (or just `scale_x_continuous(expand = c(1.1, 1.1))` if you don't want to explicitly pick).

Comment: I am not sure that anything is wrong. Probability density function **can** be greater than 1. The only constraint on it is that it needs to be non negative and the area under it has to be = 1. Perhaps you want to plot the histogram?

Comment: this answer may help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48109/what-does-the-y-axis-in-a-kernel-density-plot-mean

i agree with musically_ut. you may want a histogram if you are plotting a discrete distribution.

Comment: You need to explain why you think these results are "wrong".

Comment: I don't understand why plotting x$p and round(x$p) give me different densities